# Java 2 Dimentional Color Array. Is it possible?

Tags: java, arrays, awt, 2d

Is a 2Dimentional Color array possible such as

```
public static Color[] worlds;
public static ArrayList<String> world = new ArrayList<String>();

public void tick() {
    for (int i = 0; i < world.size(); i++) { //lets say world has 6 values in it
        worlds[i] = new Color(0, 0, 0, 100);
    }
}
```

The only problem is when I try to change the color of i in the worlds, it returns a NullPointerException. Any Ideas? If necessary I can provide full class file, and explain in detail what it is supposed to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `worlds` array has not been initialised, and therefore is null. You need to initialise it before accessing it:

```
worlds = new Color[world.size()];
for (int i = 0; i < world.size(); i++) {
    ...
{
```

Comment: Still seems to crash. But this time returning an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

Comment: Have you tried running it in a debugger so you can see exactly what is going on?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with debug mode. What would I be looking for?

Comment: In your development environment (IDE) of choice, set a breakpoint on a line of code above where the problem is, then start the debugger and step through the code one line at a time, examining the values of the variables at each step to make sure they are what you expect. Eventually (hopefully) you will come across the line of code that is not doing what you expect it to do.

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out. Turns out the line you told me to put int `worlds = new Color[world.size()];` was only being called when the game first loaded (and the arraylist get filled when you press the button to get to the load menu) so the list was allways empty. But now it works! Thanks.